# Pentaho CE - Parameter Authentification

Tags: authentication, parameters, pentaho

I just wanna know if it's possbile to have a parameter or variable in **Pentaho CE 5.0.1** when users log , so in that case each user will have his own report and cube in function of that parameter.

Thank you ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you, you want to restrict data based on user name.

*Example*: User A can see Cube filtered to to Products from A department.

I used these 3 pages to implement such settings.
Try [here](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?137028-Establishing-security-in-a-cube-filtering-a-database-table), [here](http://wiki.pentaho.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=9799803) and [here](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Using+System+Actions+to+Control+Data+Access).

Comment: Yes, I want the filter the cube in function of user's name or id,
I will check this solution ,
Thanks :)

Comment: If you have problem implementing it, publish your progress so we can help you.

Comment: Hi , 
The first problem is I don't find the folder for xaction

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is by assigning roles to different types of users and enabling cube security. You may grant role A the right to view a cube/schema/dimension/member and deny it to another.

As for content itself (reports, dashboards), you manage that from within Pentaho User Console by adding permissions either to a role or to a user.

Comment: Hi ,
The problem when I have a big number of user and how can I identify the user connected ?

Comment: That's why you assign them roles. Each user may have any combination of roles (e.g., User,Business Analyst, Sales Data EMEA, etc.).

Comment: is it possbile to do it in this way like 
, one user can see his products only ?

Comment: Simplest way, but impractical if you have hundreds or thousands of users: assign each user his own role.